# Xcode time difference in minutes fails

Tags: xcode, timestamp

quick question I used the following code to retrieve a difference between two timestamps.
The minutes are given to me now in 0.5 hrs.
how do I get that into minutes (NSInteger format)?

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"];
NSDate* firstDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"06:00"];
NSDate* secondDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"17:30"];
NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [secondDate timeIntervalSinceDate:firstDate];
```

I'm using an NSInteger to get the full hours, but can't figure out the minutes... must be too late at night for me :-/

```
    NSInteger hoursBetweenDates = timeDifference / 60;
NSInteger minutesBetweenDates = ??;

NSLog(@"RAW: %f", timeDifference);
NSLog(@"Hours: %i", hoursBetweenDates);
NSLog(@"Minutes: %i", minutesBetweenDates);
```

Thanks guys! :-D

Answer (score 0):

The NSTimeInterval is in seconds. So minutes would be diff/60.0 and hours would be diff/3600.0.

Comment: my RAW output reads 690, and if I divide 690 by 60, I get 11.5 which is 11 hours and .5 hrs (aka 30 min), but how do I get to the 30 minutes in programming, I know it's 0.5*60=30 to get there, but since some of my variables are type int, NSTimeInterval and all mixed up, how do I do that? arrrggghh :-(

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting 690 for your raw value. It should be 41400 (11.5 hours * 3600 secs). I don't have a computer handy, so I can't test your DateFormatter's output. Also, is there any particular reason you're converting to int? You'd be much better off sticking with NSTimeInterval otherwise.

Comment: Oops, I just noticed your date formatter is specifying minutes & seconds, not hours and minutes! Fix that and you should see better results!

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [secondDate timeIntervalSinceDate:firstDate];
int minute = (int)timeDifference % 3600 / 60;
```

Comment: That throws an error:

Invalid Operants to binary expression ('NSTimeinterval' aka double and double)